# "The Japanese are a hard-working people." Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, copular-verbs

I came across this statement. Is this correct? I am specifically confused at the part where "a" comes after "are".

Comment: Yes, it is correct.  "Are" is referring to "The Japanese", which is plural. "A" is referring to the group "hard-working people", and while there are many in a group, it is a single group of people.

Comment: Also, if the Japanese were the only (or most extremely) hard-working people and that comparison to other people was a point, you might use "**the** hard-working people".  "**A** hard-working people" means the Japanese are one example of hard-working people.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's correct. *People* is a noun like any other. It can be a collective noun standing alone as in:

> There were people everywhere in the hall.

Or it can be a singular noun, taking 'a' or 'the', referring to a race, nationality or culture of people. In this form it can also become plural - [peoples.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_indigenous_peoples)

**Edit**
The plural verb 'are' is used because it belongs with *The Japanese* [people], a  plural collective noun. Compare:

> [American crocodiles](http://earthsbirthday.org/images/uploads/growing/amazon-rainforest-ecosystem.pdf) are **a species** with the scientific name *Crocodylus
>   acustus.*

Or:

> [Neanderthals](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/earth/environment/archaeology/10159142/Neanderthals-were-house-proud-new-cave-excavations-reveal.html) were **a house-proud race** who liked to return to home
>   comforts, fresh excavations of caves in Gibraltar have revealed.

Comment: Myna, strange, Merriam-Webster doesn't have an entry for "peoples". It reads: "people: "Inflected Form(s): plural *people*".

Comment: @Carlo_R. : But AHD and Collins do. I usually stick with them.

Comment: Would the downvoter like to give a  reason?

Comment: @Carlo_R. There’s a huge difference between saying *these people* and saying *these peoples*.

Comment: @tchrist, and in reference to Italians, as an instance, what would you say "these people" or "these peoples"?

Comment: @Carlo_R. If we posit that “the Italians” comprise a single people, and I think we can, then of course it is *these people, these Italians*.